# xgb.train is working but xgb.cv is not Error: Invalid shape of labels

Tags: python-3.x, xgboost, cross-validation, gridsearchcv

I am trying to run xgb.cv but it is throwing error there are no null values in my dataset and df type is int64. My target class is binary 0 and 1

```
X_train.shape
```

returning (431,58)

```
y_train.shape
```

returning (431,1)

```
import xgboost as xgb

dtrain_clf = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, y_train)
dtest_clf = xgb.DMatrix(X_test, y_test)
```

```
params = {"objective": "binary:logistic", "tree_method": "hist",'num_class': 2 }
n = 1000

results = xgb.cv(params,
                 dtrain_clf,
                 num_boost_round=n,
                 nfold=10,
                 metrics=["mlogloss", "auc", "merror"]
                )
```

Error I am getting is:

XGBoostError: [17:58:51] C:\buildkite-agent\builds\buildkite-windows-cpu-autoscaling-group-i-07593ffd91cd9da33-1\xgboost\xgboost-ci-windows\src\objective\regression_obj.cu:52: Check failed: info.labels.Size() == preds.Size() (387 vs. 774) : Invalid shape of labels.

I have almost everything to make this working but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing "binary:logistic" to "multi:softprob" keeping "num_class": 2.